# Storing variable in session with ejs and node js

Tags: node.js, express, session-variables

Im trying to think of a solution to the following issue:
I have a variable that needs to be separate for every unique visitor on the page. Its just simple list that is filled when a visitor clicks on some items on the page. It would be empty for each unique visit.
Currently Im keeping that in the backend, it is pretty bad solution as everyone currently using the app is adding to the same list

The backend code:

```
thelist=[]

app.get("/show/:id", function (req, res) {
 var id = req.params.id;
 thelist.push(id)
 console.log(thelist);
 res.redirect('/')
});

app.get("/run", function(req, res) {
 res.render("data", {data: thelist})
 thelist = []
});
```

The main point is that list `thelist` is then passed to a python script which is also connected via node.js into the app. Therefore i need that variable to stay in the backend.
Also I was thinking of keeping it simple, so I don't want to force users to create account to use the app, so some sort of cookies/cache/any other form of session storage is what im looking for.

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. What kind of list is it? Should it be stored on client side? And is it necessary to pass it to server side then? *Currently Im keeping that in the backend, it is pretty bad solution* - not necessarily bad. Obviously, you need to use sessions or another way to authenticate users.

Comment: The thing is I dont want to authenticate users. I want to keep it simple. So if somoene uses the app from different browser it views it as separate instace/session. I have to pass it to server side as that list is used by a python script that is connected via node.js .

Comment: If you don't want it, you won't get an app that works as intended, simple as that. Authentication doesn't mean asking users for credentials. It means that you can verify user identity. With sessions. Or anonymous JWTs. Not by IPs.

Comment: I mean i would like to use some sort of sessions but without authentication.

Comment: Anonymous authentication is still authentication. This is what happens when you identify a user by session id. Terminology doesn't mean much here, but you will have better chances to find what you're looking for when you know it. As I mentioned, you can use a session like cookie-based https://github.com/expressjs/session , or anonymous JWT, or something else.

Comment: Ok I get it but i’m wondering how can I implement session variable using for example express session.

Comment: Check my easiest way in answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a session map(like hashmaps). I have integrated the same in one of my projects and it is working flawlessly. Below is the code for it and how you can access it:

**hashmap.js**

```
var hashmapSession = {};

exports.auth = auth = {
  set : function(key, value){
    hashmapSession[key] = value;
  },
  get : function(key){
    return hashmapSession[key];
  },
  delete : function(key){
    delete hashmapSession[key];
  },
  all : function(){
    return hashmapSession;
  }
};
```

**app.js**

```
var hashmap = require('./hashmap');
var testObj = { id : 1, name : "john doe" };

hashmap.auth.set('test', testObj);
hashmap.auth.get('test');
hashmap.auth.all();
hashmap.auth.delete('test');
```

You can use this approach as a session storage for your node application. Keep in mind that this storage will only be persistent for the current session only.

Comment: So do I need to use express session with it?

Comment: because using it plainly as you suggested it still adds to the same list on different browsers.

Comment: this method is independent of the session and cookies of the browser. The values are stored as a temporary map in server's memory. instead of storing the data in same key use dynamic keys which will be the identification of different browsers. You can try fingerprint js by valve in your template which will help you in identification of unique visitors. https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2

Answer (score 1):

The best solution here would be **express session** (https://github.com/expressjs/session)

As I see your code I can figure out you are using **express**. And if you are using express that is enough for below code.

### Here is the easiest way with minimal code to achieve what you are looking for:

Example:

```
app.set('oneSetting', 'one');
console.log(app.settings.oneSetting);
```

OR

```
   app.set('port', 3000);

   app.get('port'); //3000
```

You can access the same variables in the req object too, example:

```
req.app.get('port')
```

Comment: So can I call the app.get('port') inside the route as a nromal variable? And I can set those to be any kind of variable I want? Like string or list.

Comment: Yes... you can do it.

Comment: Hmm I tried your suggestions and I guess I need to include it inside express session? Because simply adding app.set instead to the code it still adds to the same list on different browsers(sessions)

Comment: Not yet, currently I'm figuring out how to include app.set() variable in express session.

Comment: `app.use(session({
  secret: '*',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true },
}))` how can i include app.set() into this?

Comment: can you the check https://github.com/expressjs/session? They have well documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use express-session.

You can use it like the following :

**App.js**

```
var app = express();
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))
```

**Controller.js**

```
//Sets the id in the session object.
app.get('/show/:id', function (request, response, next) {
  request.session.id = id;
})

//Retrieve the id from the session object.
app.get('/showMyId',function(request,response,next)){
  response.send(request.session.id;);
})
```

This way you do not have to manage the global list and all your ids would be present inside their respective session object.

This approach uses a cookie session , there are also alternative strategies available for storing your session object like a proper storage server.

Comment: The thing is i need that as a list of ids because i send it to a python script which requires that to be in form of a list.

Comment: In that case i would suggest the answer below by Jack, by using app.set/get.

Comment: @AlexT You mean an array?

Comment: Yes in javascript it would be array

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you are trying to count no.of unique visitors for your application.

You can use simple cookie to track use and set expiry long time so cookie is not erased.

Express had [cookie parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) module which will automatically parse cookie.

```js
thelist={}

var express      = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
 
var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get("/show/:id", function (req, res) {
 var visitorId = req.cookies.visitorid;
 var id = req. params.id
 if(!req.cookies[id]){
  ///create unique id like GUID or something which allows you to uniquely identify user
  if(!visitorId){
    visitorId = '<GUID>';
  }
  if(!thelist[visitorId]){
    thelist[visitorId] = [];
  }
  thelist[visitorId].push(id);
  console.log(thelist);
 }
 res.cookie('visitorid',visitorId, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true }); //You can extend max age as required. Setting up every time will also extend expiry.
 res.cookie(id,'visited', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true }); //set cookie with id saying this is allready visited
 res.redirect('/')
});

app.get("/run", function(req, res) {
 res.render("data", {data: thelist})
 thelist = []
});
```

Comment: Not really, the id in that route is coming from api, not from the user session.

Comment: So do you want track based on ID/visitor, or id + visitor?

Comment: I meant that the show/:id route is the route that a visitor can click and then it will add that id parameter from that route to the list that should be separate for each unique visitor (‘thelist’ variable)

Comment: ok now got it you want to track per visitor what he/she has all-ready visited

Comment: updated with same only problem is that cookie has limit so if you have so many id limit will be overflowed. In that case i suggest you maintain list in localStorage and pass cookie based on that.

Comment: You mean that the cookie which containts lists for different users can only store that much?

Comment: Im getting error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined` at this line: `if(!req.cookie[id]){`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177122/discussion-between-rohit-harkhani-and-alex-t).

Answer (score -1):

you can use sessionstorage on your window session

```
sessionStorage.setItem(KEY,VALUE);
```

Comment: Your solution is for in-browser storage, not node.js apps.